# getting below error while doing pip install in windows 7 python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, pip

Any help would be appreciated, I'm getting the error below while installing the any python package using pip install. pip install installed from get-pip.py.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main 
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 750, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 587, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 661, in unpack_http_url
    rmtree(temp_dir)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 249, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 110, in rmtree_errorhandler
    if os.stat(path).st_mode & stat.S_IREAD:
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\ganesr01\\appdata\\local\\
temp\\pip-nhsft2-unpack\\pypiwin32-219-cp27-none-win32.whl'
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting a WindowsError so try re running and open the cmd windows as admin

Comment: @Alastair, Thanks for the reply. but same error from Admin cmd window also

Comment: Apparently it's in the middle of calling `shutil.rmtree` on the directory. If the file has already been deleted but has yet to be unlinked (maybe because some kernel component such as a malware scanner still has a reference), then it's still in the directory listing but trying to open it, even to `stat` it, will fail with access denied. Does it leave the `%TEMP%\pip-nhsft2-unpack` directory in place after it fails? Does this directory have the wheel file `pypiwin32-219-cp27-none-win32.whl` and can you read it (it's a zip file)?

Comment: Deleting a file in Windows sets the delete disposition on the underlying file control block, but a file doesn't get unlinked until all kernel File object references have been closed. Until then, existing kernel `File` object references can access the file; they can even be used to unset the delete disposition to restore it. But so long as it's 'deleted', no new references can be opened for any access.

Answer (score 1):

Re-run the command except open up command prompt as admin

Edit: If that doesn't work it looks like you do not have permissions to write to that folder You need to change the permissions on those folders.

Comment: The file is in the OP's own `%TEMP%` directory, created by the OP's own process. The odds of it being a permission problem are slim to none.